# How do i create 2 columns with 6 rows in the center?

Tags: html, css

im new to HTML/CSS and working since friday on my own website but now im stucked and dont know how to solve my problem.

I want to create a "abilities" part on my homepage where i can add to each "skill" 5 stars (some are filled, others arent).

For example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kORt.png)

So i need help at creating the marked red area.

My HTML Code for this part in the screenshot is:

```
<div id="abilities">
          <h2>Abilities</h2>
          <p class="quotes">"Most good programmers do programming not because they expect to get paid or get adulation by the public, but because it is fun to program."<br>- Linus Torvalds</p>

           <hr />

           <h3>Skills</h3>

           </div>
```

I googled for answered but couldnt find the right answer for me.

I would apprectiate it when someone could help out.

I know the easiest possiblity would be like this:

```
<div>
<p>HTML <img src="star-filled1.png"><img src="star-filled1.png"><img src="star1.png"><img src="star1.png"><img src="star1.png"></p>
</div>
```

and change all the paddings in the css file.. but i feel like its not professional and it would take much more time.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to post what you have tried thus far?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or any other design framework ?

Comment: @fubar i have tried nothing so far. I found a page of a guy who had the same idea as i have. I looked at his his code and couldnt figure out how he has done it. Here is his page: http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/profile

Comment: @Zaid Bin Khalid Uhm no not yet. I wanted to create my own website with basic things like html and css to understand it. 

Because im trying to find a job where i can work with java, html and css. And thats why im learning it this way.

And yeah i was seeing the same example on a other page.. Is this guy using bootstrap on his own page? 
http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/profile He is using <ul> and <li> tags. And also <span> like you did in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```css
#wrapper {

 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 5px solid red;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: auto;
 font-weight: bold;

}

#left {

 float: left;
 width: 45%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {

 float: right;
 width: 45%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#col1, #col2 {
    float: left;
 }

#col1 {

 width: 85%;

}

#col2 {
  
 width: 15%;


}

p {
line-height: 100%;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 5px;
}


.wrap {

 float: right;

 
}

.blue {

 color: skyblue;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {

 p {
  font-size: 24px; 
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 630px) {

 p {
  font-size: 15px; 
 }
}
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="left">
    <div id="col1">

     <p>Html<span class="wrap">
     <span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>
     </p>
     <p>Css<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     <p>Java<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     <p>Android<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     <p>JavaScript<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     
    </div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="right">
    <div id="col1">

     <p>My-Sql<span class="wrap">
     <span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>
     </p>
     <p>Jquery<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     <p>XML<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     <p>PHP<span class="wrap"><span class="blue">&#x2605;&#x2605;</span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;</span></p>
     
    </div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Sigi Sixx , If This Post Help you,Mark it Or Give it Vote Up Please!

Comment: Got one more problem, i changed the font-size and now the words are not in the same row as the stars. Is there any way to increase the space between the words?
Here is a screenshot of the problem:
https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/33173079/how.png

Comment: @Sigi Sixx , I Updated my post,See it.i hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with old approach and use table, and format your page as a table
Or you can go with bootstrap approach and use rows and columns grid to format your page this way.
You also can write same code in your own css like bootstrap, in that case you need to configure multiple divs with width in "%", like width:49% for each div. 
If you post your code that you have so far, it will become easier to tell you in which direction you should continue research.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some design framework then let me know otherwise you can do like this.

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  max-width:1200px;
  padding:15px;
  margin:0px auto;
 }
 .row{
  margin:0px auto;
  width:100%;
 }
 .text-col{
  width:20%;
  max-width:250px;
  color:#333;
  font-weight:500;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  float:left;
 }
 .rating-col{
  width:30%;
  max-width:350px;
  float:left;
 }
 .clear{
  clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>HTML</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>Mysql</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>CSS</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>JQuery</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>Java</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>XML</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>Android</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-col">
     <strong>PHP</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-col">
     <span>start images/icons</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see this @SigiSixx

Comment: Thanks! This looks great! I will modify everything. Change sizes and post the end result!

Comment: one more question. When i want that all letters start in the same column and not in the center, how can i do that?

Comment: Ive got one problem. In my style.css ive got this part: 

.abilities {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:white;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    font-family: orator Std;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;

And because of the "text-align" everything is in the center. Also your code. How can i change that?

Comment: I dont understand, I thing you need to see this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: Thanks =D I had to add into your code just "text-align: initial" to set this value to default!

Answer (score 0):

As some other replies have mentioned this is very easy to do using a framework such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (foundation, semantic ui). My suggestion would be checking out some examples on how these "star" ratings are marked up, another tip would be to checkout something like [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) for the star icons instead of images.

There is hundreds of ways to achieve this, so if you get stuck I'm happy help you with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use flex. A `dl` list can be used to reduce html to minimum, any similar structure will do too

example

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: red solid;
  padding: 2em 80px 2em 20px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top left,silver,tomato,gold,gray)
}

dt {
  width: 120px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0.1em 0;
}

dd {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 120px;
  color: rgba(0, 162, 234, 0);
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,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) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: auto 20px
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>HTML</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>MYSQL</dt>
  <dd>skills 5</dd>
  <dt><del>CSS</del> ;)</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>JQuery</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>JAVA</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>XML</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>ANDROIDS</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>PhP</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
  <dt>JavaScript</dt>
  <dd>details</dd>
</dl>
```